# Lisp sorting and scoring

Tags: list, sorting, lisp

I am trying to make a `score function` using lisp. The idea is that I have a list as input. This list must be sorted and each value should get a mark (the firest one has the highest mark)
I tried something like the normal sort, but i need to use the lambda operator

But my lisp is pretty bad .

An example to make it clear:
    ((o1 10 15 20) (o2 5 14 20) (o3 7 8 8)
output>
    ((o1 1 1 1) (o2 3 2 1) (o3 2 3 3))

it sorts the firest value from o1 with first from o2 and first from o3 and it ranks them .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually can't understand your question. But if the question is: "Help me to sort a list in common lisp" then:

1) `(setq o1 (20 30 15)) is a valid lisp expression and (20 30 15) is a list, but it is not quoted, so the interpreter will try to evaluate expression. And the rule of evaluation is "First element in expression is a function" so interpreter will try to evaluate a function that has a name "20" and will fail. You should write this:

```
(setq o1 '(20 30 15))
```

1') Usually it is better to use `setf` instead of `setq` (especially if you don't want to know the difference). And also it's better to define variable before setting a value to it. So it's better to write something like this:

```
(defparameter o1 '()) ;creating o1 with empty list
(setf o1 '(20 30 15))
```

1'') You should name you variables and function with understandable names. And if it is a global variable mark it with asterisks. For example

```
(defparameter *students-scores* '())
(setf *students-scores* '(20 30 15))
```

2) In common lisp `list` is a built in function that creates a list from it's arguments. Even if you are in your own package at the time this code will be executed (the default package is locked so you won't be able to redefine `list` function there), it is quite strange to redefine such function as `list`, so choose another name for your function

```
(defun sort-integer-list (lst)
  (sort lst #'<))
```

3) You have parentheses mismatch in you code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and explaning me.
What I do not understand is how can i sort the first element of first sublist with the first from the 2nd sublist.
(i edited the first post)

Comment: @StereoView Sorry, but I still can't understand what you want. ) Please explain the question in more readable form.
P.S. I don't know the word "firest" and the dictionary gave me nothing.